# Are Kotlin mutable collections thread-safe?

Tags: kotlin, collections, thread-safety

Despite reading the [Kotlin's documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/#kotlin.collections.MutableMap) about collections  I can't find if Kotlin's mutable collections are [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) and if there are any concurrent alternative implementations (Like [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) vs [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) in Java)

Note: I refer to the collections created by Kotlin when we do:

```
mutableMapOf<>()
mutableListOf<>()
mutableSetOf<>()
```

Comment: Collection is an interface, so it does not enforce anything regarding thread safety.

Comment: Regarding your edit : same, those create mere ArrayLists or LinkedHashMaps, so nothing thread safe here. Anyway, you shoudl be good to go by using any Java thread safe implementation you want instead of those.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no thread-safety guarantee for the collections returned by `mutableMapOf` (`MutableMap`), `mutableListOf` (`MutableList`), or `mutableSetOf` (`MutableSet`).

To achieve thread safety, you can wrap them with the corresponding Java Collections wrapper:

```kotlin
val myThreadSafeMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(mutableMapOf())
```

Comment: Or use a JVM-specific thread-safe implementation, like `ConcurrentHashMap` for Map, `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` for Set, or `CopyOnWriteArrayList` for List.